# Generate PDF with only Tj Operator

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, adobe-illustrator, cs3

I want to generate PDF  files or convert the existing PDF files that uses Tj operator to denote the string with Tl to denote text lead and it should not contain the TJ operator and TD operator. What i have to set in the settings of acrobat distiller server 6.0.1 or adobe illustrator. Help me in this issue.

Currently i am using these operator to identify and search the text and store them as a dictionary for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Distiller supports anything of the sort.

I suggest you find a better way to extract your text.  Even if all your text uses `Tj` instead of one of the other text display operators (not just TJ), you're still in trouble if you run into a custom encoding.  Let someone else who's already solved this problem do it for you.

There are Lots of programs out there that can do a fairly good job of extracting text from a PDF.  The best is still Acrobat/Reader... so if you cannot select/copy/paste the text out of Reader, then no other software will be able to work either... save OCR (**O** potical **C** haracter **R** ecognition).

I'm biased towards [iText](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) (Java) and [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) (C#)... I'm a committer.  None the less, there are quite a few other applications out there doing basically the same thing... sitting in various places on the freeware/Free Software/Commercial spectrum.  Heck, the iTexts sit in several places on that spectrum.  :rolleyes: